# Wordpress keeps repeating posts in custom news page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a custom WordPress theme from scratch. I have created a custom posts page using custom css to form a sort of News page but uses posts as the "news articles". I have the page set up to show a featured news article and a rss feed next to the featured article then side by side posts following beneath the featured area. I'm running into an issue where WordPress is repeating the post 3x then does it again underneath with the next post. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Everything I've looked up isn't exactly like the issue I'm running into. I'll post code.
This is the PHP code:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>News</h1>
</div>
<!--/Wrapper-->
</div>
<!--/Header Text-->
<!--Flexbox Content-->
<div class="littleBody White">
  <!--Little Body-->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!--Wrapper-->
    <div class="news">

      <?php
              if(have_posts() ){
                while(have_posts() ){
                  the_post();
                  get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'archive');
                }
              }
            ?>
        <?php
              the_posts_pagination();
            ?>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/Wrapper-->
```

This is the HTML I'm working from:

```css
.news-main-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 0.5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 25px;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.articles-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 25px;
}

.feat-article img {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.feat-article h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.feat-author-img,
.news-author-img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.feat-author-img p,
.news-author-img p {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.feat-author-img img,
.news-author-img img {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.rss-feed h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.rss-feed img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.rss-feed-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.news2 img,
.news3 img {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.news-author-img img {
  width: 15%;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<section class="news">
  <div class="news-main-grid-container">
    <div class="feat-article">
      <div class="rss-feed-mobile">
        <h3>Social Media</h3>
        <img src="images\stockPhotos\RedFlowers.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <!--/RSS Feed-->
      <img src="images\stockPhotos\BouquetOfFlowers.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>Featured Article Header</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet tristique lacus. Vestibulum ac magna eget est commodo rutrum. Fusce in nibh vehicula, porttitor massa quis, vulputate libero. Maecenas auctor pretium quam non lobortis. Curabitur
        posuere lacus tortor, sed viverra est porttitor in. Nunc cursus, sapien pharetra interdum hendrerit, tellus ex fermentum dolor, a hendrerit mauris ex a nisl. Mauris bibendum vestibulum purus at tempus. Pellentesque in tempus tellus, id cursus
        tortor. Nunc dictum in diam vitae dictum. Donec id odio ullamcorper, tempor nisl sit amet, posuere orci. Nunc pellentesque magna eget magna consectetur molestie. Proin eget turpis vitae metus dignissim fringilla quis vel massa. Proin consequat
        interdum magna, et venenatis nulla vestibulum vel. Curabitur tempus lectus sit amet ex consectetur, pretium aliquet tellus faucibus.</p>
      <div class="feat-author-img">
        <img src="images\stockPhotos\PurpleFlower.jpg" alt="">
        <p>David Hosbach<br>Aug 28th, 2020</p>
      </div>
      <!--/Author Img-->
    </div>
    <!--/Featured Article-->
    <div class="rss-feed">
      <h3>Social Media</h3>
      <img src="images\stockPhotos\RedFlowers.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <!--/RSS Feed-->
  </div>
  <!--/Feat Grid Container-->
  <div class="articles-grid-container">
    <div class="news2">
      <img src="images\stockPhotos\BouquetOfFlowers.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>Featured Article Header</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet tristique lacus. Vestibulum ac magna eget est commodo rutrum. Fusce in nibh vehicula, porttitor massa quis, vulputate libero. Maecenas auctor pretium quam non lobortis. Curabitur
        posuere lacus tortor, sed viverra est porttitor in. Nunc cursus, sapien pharetra interdum hendrerit, tellus ex fermentum dolor, a hendrerit mauris ex a nisl. Mauris bibendum vestibulum purus at tempus. Pellentesque in tempus tellus, id cursus
        tortor. Nunc dictum in diam vitae dictum. Donec id odio ullamcorper, tempor nisl sit amet, posuere orci. Nunc pellentesque magna eget magna consectetur molestie. Proin eget turpis vitae metus dignissim fringilla quis vel massa. Proin consequat
        interdum magna, et venenatis nulla vestibulum vel. Curabitur tempus lectus sit amet ex consectetur, pretium aliquet tellus faucibus.</p>
      <div class="news-author-img">
        <img src="images\stockPhotos\PurpleFlower.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Chris Hosbach<br>Aug 26th, 2020</p>
      </div>
      <!--/News Author Img-->
    </div>
    <!--/News 2-->
    <div class="news3">
      <img src="images\stockPhotos\BouquetOfFlowers.jpg" alt="">
      <h2>Featured Article Header</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet tristique lacus. Vestibulum ac magna eget est commodo rutrum. Fusce in nibh vehicula, porttitor massa quis, vulputate libero. Maecenas auctor pretium quam non lobortis. Curabitur
        posuere lacus tortor, sed viverra est porttitor in. Nunc cursus, sapien pharetra interdum hendrerit, tellus ex fermentum dolor, a hendrerit mauris ex a nisl. Mauris bibendum vestibulum purus at tempus. Pellentesque in tempus tellus, id cursus
        tortor. Nunc dictum in diam vitae dictum. Donec id odio ullamcorper, tempor nisl sit amet, posuere orci. Nunc pellentesque magna eget magna consectetur molestie. Proin eget turpis vitae metus dignissim fringilla quis vel massa. Proin consequat
        interdum magna, et venenatis nulla vestibulum vel. Curabitur tempus lectus sit amet ex consectetur, pretium aliquet tellus faucibus.</p>
      <div class="news-author-img">
        <img src="images\stockPhotos\PurpleFlower.jpg" alt="">
        <p>David Hosbach<br>Aug 15th, 2020</p>
      </div>
      <!--/News Author Pic-->
    </div>
    <!--/News 3-->
  </div>
  <!--/Articles Grid Container-->
</section>
<!--/Section-->
```

[Stage Site](https://o51.233.myftpupload.com/?page_id=2912)

What on earth am I doing wrong????

Edit: I was asked to post the content-archive code so here it is:

```html
<div class="news-main-grid-container">
  <div class="feat-article">
    <div class="rss-feed-mobile">

    </div>
    <!--/RSS Feed-->
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
    <a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <h2>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h2>
    </a>
    <p>
      <?php
          the_excerpt();
        ?>
    </p>
    <div class="feat-author-img">
      <p>
        <?php the_author(); ?><br>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/Author Img-->
  </div>
  <!--/Featured Article-->
  <div class="rss-feed">

  </div>
  <!--/RSS Feed-->
</div>
<!--/Feat Grid Container-->

<div class="articles-grid-container">
  <div class="news2">
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
    <a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <h2>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h2>
    </a>
    <p>
      <?php
          the_excerpt();
        ?>
    </p>
    <div class="news-author-img">
      <p>
        <?php the_author(); ?><br>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/News Author Img-->
  </div>
  <!--/News 2-->
  <div class="news3">
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
    <a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <h2>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h2>
    </a>
    <p>
      <?php
          the_excerpt();
        ?>
    </p>
    <div class="news-author-img">
      <!-- <img src="images\stockPhotos\PurpleFlower.jpg" alt=""> -->
      <p>
        <?php the_author(); ?><br>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/News Author Img-->
  </div>
  <!--/News 3-->
</div>
<!--/Articles Grid Container-->
```

Comment: `while(have_posts())` does it iterate?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show us what's in your `content-archive.php`. This has nothing to do with your CSS. So, you can remove that from the question. Replace the HTML you posted with the content of your `content-archive.php`.

Comment: I edited the post to add my content-archive code as well

Comment: Yeah, the problem is in your `content-archive.php`. In your main loop, you are calling that template. In that template, you are repeating the post three times. The thing to remember is that for **each** post in the loop you are calling `content-archive.php` so the data doesn't change for each of the `the_title`, `the_excerpt`, etc.

Comment: So how do I fix it then? I'm not 100% knowledgeable on how to fix it. I want a featured article with the rss feed next to it then the rest of the posts or articles to follow in 2 columns below. I have custom css for whatever is the newest post or whatever we want as the featured post and then css for the next sections or 2 column grid if you will. Nothing I have looked up is close to what I'm trying to achieve. Unless this is something that's just completely out of my skills at the moment to do.

Comment: It's entirely possible, but what you're asking is a bit out of the scope of Stack Overflow - since it's a large feature to code. How are you defining the "featured article"? Are you using the "sticky post" feature? Depending on the answer, we can probably lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I didn't even know that sticky post feature is a thing. I'm learning as I go along with the basic CMS things I've learned and watching on youtube and those things. Maybe I need more learning before I try this any further.

Comment: Yeah, sticky posts are a thing. If you give me a little time, I can put together a quick code block for you to test things out on.

Comment: Yes, I have time. I'm currently looking into how I can sneak a rss feed next to the sticky post. Haha

Comment: I fixed the archive-content page. It's not repeating any longer so great but now I don't have my side by side post content but that is for a different post I think! Thanks for all your help!